# How many frontend public ip can we configure in google cloud https load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

What are the limitations of GCP https global load balancer. I am trying to scale out my GLB , currently it has only 1 public ip address. Wanted to know how much I can scale so that accordingly I can design a solution.

Comment: What do you mean **scale out my GLB**? The Google load balancer is global. Adding IPs does not scale a Google load balancer. The load balancer scales automatically based on traffic, not something you configure. Read this article to understand GCLB: https://sre.google/workbook/managing-load/ Also read the section on Anycast so that you understand that a single IP address is global and not a single point of entry.

Answer (score 3):

As @John Hanley suggested The load balancer scales automatically based on traffic, not something you configure. So,The global external HTTP(S) load balancers are implemented by many proxies called Google Front Ends (GFEs). There isn't just a single proxy. In Premium Tier, the same global external IP address is advertised from various points of presence, and client requests are directed to the client's nearest GFE.
Depending on where your clients are, multiple GFEs can initiate HTTP(S) connections to your backends. Packets sent from GFEs have source IP addresses from the same range used by health check probers: 35.191.0.0/16 and 130.211.0.0/22.

Refer to [Doc1](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#global-classic-connections) and [Doc2](https://cloud.google.com/docs/security/infrastructure/design#google_front_end_service) for more information.